# Returning Function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to write a program that will use a variable to call a function, I defined the variable `var X;` as a global variable and initialized it on `startGame()` function. Problem is if I'm running `startGame()` once, then calling `X();` as a function works fine but say I put it in a loop, it runs on first iteration and when it returns, it says `Uncaught TypeError: X is not a function`. Being new to Javascript I'm confused and I need help on how using variable as function works.

```
var X,
i=0,
lastmove = 100;     //Randomly initialize function

function A(){
    console.log('A');
}

function B(){
    console.log('B');
}

function C(){
    console.log('C');
}

function pickFunc(){
    var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    if(temp==lastmove)
        temp = pickFunc()
    else
        lastStr = temp;

    if(temp == 1)
        return A();
    else if(temp == 2)
        return B();
    else
        return C();
}

function startGame(){
    X = pickFunc();
    for(i; i<10; i++)
        X()
}
```

Comment: `return A` etc ... because `return A()` returns the result of calling `A`

Comment: I just did that, it ran just once still, next line said `undefined`

Comment: `for(i; i<10; i++)` ... `for(var i=0; i<10; i++)` makes more sense - except it would call X() 10 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `X = pickFunc();` at the end, you're assigning the RESULT of `pickFunc()` to `X`.

It seems you intend to alias the function so you can call `X()` in place of `pickFunc()`. To do this with minimal changes to your code you would change that line to:

```
X = pickFunc;
```

This will make it so overtime you call `X()`, it reevaluates `pickFunc()`.

Comment: ??? `X = pickFunc` without parameters should be sufficient. Of course, OP is not making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are returning the **result** of calling the functions `A`, `B` and `C` inside of `pickFunc` when you need to be returning a **reference** to them. Try the following code:

```
function pickFunc(){
    var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    if(temp==lastmove)
        temp = pickFunc()
    else
        lastStr = temp;

    if(temp == 1)
        return A;
    else if(temp == 2)
        return B;
    else
        return C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0;
var lastmove = 100;     //Randomly initialize function

function A(){
    console.log('A');
}

function B(){
    console.log('B');
}

function C(){
    console.log('C');
}

var X = function pickFunc(){
    var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    if(temp==lastmove)
        temp = pickFunc()
    else
        lastStr = temp;

    if(temp == 1)
        return A();
    else if(temp == 2)
        return B();
    else
        return C();
}

function startGame(){
    for(i; i<10; i++)
        X()
}
```

Comment: You can asign a var to a function when you create it, just do this way and it will fucntion